# nested json by using stored procedure call

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, json, stored-procedures

```
[
    {
    "name": "student1",
    "projects": 
    [
        {
        "name": "Project1",
        "tasks": 
                [
                    {
                    "name": "task1",
                    "id": 2
                    }
                ],
        "id": 6
        }
    ]
},
```

etc....

I want to make json data like this. Now i am calling one stored procedure to fetch student information and by iterating student result and calling project stored procedure by student Id. I want to optimize this operation. I don't think this is right way of calling. Kindly help me.

Comment: "FOR XML" generally "splits" it out hierarchically for you, based on your joins (or subqueries).  You could start with that in mind and then work towards outputting in JSON.  Can't say more without some code.

Comment: Thanks for the replay. Its helped a lot. Do you have any sample code to get xml and stored into my class object(json structure)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use TSQL FORXML to get the XML Heirarchy.  Then use the below (as starting point), where strOrigObject is the string you are sending in:

```
//Declare the object for return (if any)
Student objWorkingObject = new Student();

//Populate into XML
XmlDocument _Doc = new XmlDocument();
_Doc.LoadXml(strOrigObject);
var ser = new System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(typeof(Student));
objWorkingObject = (Student)ser.Deserialize(new XmlNodeReader(_Doc.DocumentElement));
```

Comment: Hi this code is not working for nested list<object>. Do you have other sample code?

Comment: This definitely worked for me for hierarchical data, just make sure your object us defined as the XML is, with <List> of Project, etc.

Comment: Thanks for the kind reply. Some names from xml is not match from object. In that case i want to only bind matched filed names. Is it possible to do like that?

Comment: Not sure.  I have had to do some translation in a "transitory" function.  Pass in generic XML and pass out Object.  I have also got around some of the work by loading the xml with a XSLT that fetched only specific tags in a format I wanted.